Is it possible to override SOAPCore 500 status code with 400?
I've built a SOAP Webservice with SOAPCore. Its all working as expected except the error handling. The returned HTTP Status code is always 500 and I want to return 400 on occasions when it’s a user error.
I can override the Fault Body Writer and send a custom message but the not the Status code.
Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can achieve this?
I have tried to set the Status code to 400 before throwing an error but it get overwritten.
